# Get text from alert in websites

Tags: python, selenium

I have the test page:

```
<input type='button' id='button' onclick="alert('foo');" value='My Button' />
```

I want get the text of alert when click at button, then I use

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import alert

phantom = webdriver.PhantomJS()
phantom.get('/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu/test.html')
phantom.find_element_by_id('button').click()
x = alert.Alert(phantom)
print(x.text)
```

But, in the last line, I get erro:

```
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open issue at the GhostDriver (webdriver for PhantomJS) issue tracker:

- [Implement all the Session Commands related to JS Alert, Prompt and Confirm](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/20)

Here is a working workaround (prints `foo`):

```
from selenium import webdriver

phantom = webdriver.PhantomJS()    
phantom.get('index.html')

phantom.execute_script("window.alert = function(msg){ window.msg = msg; };")

phantom.find_element_by_id('button').click()

alert_text = phantom.execute_script("return window.msg;")
print(alert_text)
```

Comment: I get the same erro, and `alert` isn't callable

Comment: @Macabeus yeah, good point. Let me try reproduce the problem. Btw, what happens in, say, Firefox?

Comment: I haven't tested with Firefox, because I need use PhantomJS. It is faster and need less memory

Comment: @Macabeus okay, updated with a linked issue and a workaround. Hope that helps.